# jquery-ui sortable: how to change the DOM of the dragging element

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I am using jquery-ui sortable, and I want to ask how do I change the DOM of the drag element (Need to add an icon to the element being dragged/sorted). So

```
 $("#list").sortable({
    helper: function(event, ui){
        ...
    }
 });
```

I am using `helper` property in this case, and according to the doc, `ui` is the element of being sorted, but how do I access the html of the element of this object. Thank you

**UPDATE**: I create a small jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/y6xtV/1/. What I want, is when I start reorder, the dragging/reordering item have a border around it, and an small icon inside it.. Please help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you want to have the helper a border and an image inside it or the "original" element which is being dragged?

Here is what I came up with. See the <kbd>[**jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/SirDerpington/y6xtV/3/)</kbd> I made.

**JS**

```
$(function () {
    $("#sortable").sortable({
        start: function (event, ui) {
            ui.item.css('border', '1px solid red').append('<span class="ui-icon ui-icon-check icons"></span>');
        },
        stop: function (event, ui) {
            //reset to no border or whatever your desired default border is
            ui.item.css('border', '');
            ui.item.children('.icons').remove();
        }
    });
    $("#sortable").disableSelection();
});
```

**CSS**

```
.icons {
    display:inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
}
#helper {
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

If you want to use `helper`

```
//sortable
helper: function (event, ui) {
    return $('<div id="helper">I am the helper<span class="ui-icon ui-icon-check icons"></span></div>');
}
```

To test the helper comment out `start` and `stop` and the other way round comment out the `helper` function.
I also added a CSS theme to add the `ui-icons`.

Not sure if you really wanted to use `helper`. A bit confusing...but my solution adds the border and image to the dragged item.

Documentation:

- [start event](http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#event-start)
- [stop event](http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#event-stop)

Comment: Thank you very much. I have a odd behavior.So when I drag/reorder the item, on chrome the dragged/reorder item is not where my cursor is. It is about 30px off to the bottom right of my cursor. This does not happen on IE9. This make me think it is a css issue. I cannot replicate this on a small scale. Do you have any theory or guess?

Comment: Glad it helped! Hard to guess. Does this occur only on Chrome or on Firefox etc. too? Does the cursor kind of jump when you start sorting or how does it behave? A solution (because I can only guess your problem) is to "force" the cursor to get set on a specified position with [cursorAt](http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#option-cursorAt). Not pretty but should work I guess.

Comment: as I expected, this is because of css, once I remove `-webkit-perspective` and `-webkit-transform-style`, everything go back to normal